# Blazor Server: Getting an 'Uncaught (in promise) WebSocket is not in the OPEN state' Error Only In Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, signalr, blazor-server-side

We have written a Blazer Server app (.NET 7.0) that is hosted on IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019. The app works fine under the latest versions of Chrome or Edge. However, a few of our users use the latest version of Firefox, and they occasionally are unable to load pages of the app. There's no rhyme or reason I can find to the inability to load, besides it is more likely to happen the longer you use the app.

Keeping the Developer Console open while using the app, I notice the following when the site fails to load: `Uncaught (in promise) WebSocket is not in the OPEN state` and `Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.`

I also occasionally notice in Chrome's Developer Console that a `101 Switching Protocols` request is sent, with a 200 response header that includes `Upgrade: websocket`. I do not know if that means that SignalR has failed in some way and 'raw' WebSockets are being used as a fallback in Chrome, perhaps indicating that Firefox is failing on its attempted fallback?

I've confirmed via `about:config` in Firefox that `network.http.http2.websockets` is set to true. I've also restarted the IIS web server, just in case that was causing an issue, as well as confirming that WebSockets is installed as part of IIS.

Other than that, I'm quite unfamiliar with SignalR and WebSockets (this is our first Blazor Server app), and my Googling and review of Stack Overflow hasn't turned up anything relevant.

My basic understanding is that we want to be using SignalR generally, which happens to use WebSockets behind the scenes, but we do not want to be using 'raw WebSockets' (as Microsoft refers to it in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0)). I also was under the impression that Blazor Server used SignalR without the need for additional configuration, but perhaps we've had it misconfigured this whole time and were just relying on a fallback.

In case it's useful, here is our `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using miniDARTS.Data;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using miniDARTS.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

// Blazor Server doesn't include HttpClient service by default.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

// Configure the database connection.
string connectionString = "";

if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
{
    connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("miniDARTSContext");
}   

else if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
{
    connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("testing");
}

var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 28));
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<miniDARTSContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

// Only run cron jobs if they are in a production environment.
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
{
    IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundService>();
            services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, PhaseChangeReportService>();
        })
        .Build();

    host.RunAsync();
}

// Add MudBlazor services.
builder.Services.AddMudServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing exactly the same problem, occurring only on Firefox browser, using both .NET 6 and .NET 7.

Comment: Me too. Only Firefox and both .NET6 and .NET7, but the Server is Nginx. No issues during development (Visual Studio 2022).

Comment: same here: firefox .NET7 (but also in .NET6 and earlier) "Uncaught (in promise) WebSocket is not in the OPEN state" in firefox, app is deployed to k8s on dev/tst/acc/prd and local we use kestrel

Comment: since some guys found it needed to delete my answer, I will add a comment, the problem you are facing is the unBeforeUnload event that is unreliable in firefox and blazor framework is using that, you can find a sample code and movie and more info on the aspnet github https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51936

Answer (score 1):

Very specific issue, COULD be a firefox bug but here are few things I can think of that can be checked:

1. IIS Manager -> Your Site -> Management section -> Configuration Editor -> Section dropdown -> system.webServer/webSocket -> Is `enabled` set to `true`?
2. IIS Manager -> Your site -> Actions pane -> Advanced Settings -> Ensure the ".NET CLR Version" is set to the correct version (e.g., ".NET CLR Version v4.0.30319" for .NET 7.0)
3. Maybe try configuring SignalR to use long polling as fallback transport, which can help in cases where WebSocket connections are unstable or not supported? :

```
  ...
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="true"></script>
<script>
  Blazor.start({
      configureSignalR: function (builder) {
          builder.withUrl('/_blazor', { transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets | signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling });
      }
  });
</script>
</body>
```

try adding signalR and websockets explicitly:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
```

```
app.UseWebSockets();
```

in Program.cs

5. Make sure Blazor and related packages are latest versions in the solution.
6. Try running it on firefox with all extensions disabled maybe?

Comment: Re 1, enabled is set to true.
Re 2, the .NET CLR Version is as you indicated.
Re 3, that code did not fix the issue, unfortunately. I continue to get functioning page views for a time in Firefox, with `Uncaught (in promise) WebSocket is not in the OPEN state` in the console. Eventually pages fail to load at all.

I did notice that the console now lists `Uncaught ReferenceError: Blazor is not defined <anonymous> https://[internalDomain]/[requestedPage]:18`. Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: @NeilWehneman Where exactly is your `blazor.server.js` loaded, and in which part of the file? I updated the script, notice the `autostart` attribute on the `script`, try that. Is there any additional scripts after the blazor.server.js is called? 2. Do you have something called `pace.js` by any chance? I added a few more items to check. As I said, it could also (maybe) be a new bug that you have found.

Comment: `blazor.server.js` is loaded in `_Layout.cshmtl`. It's loaded at the very end of the `<body>` element, right after a write / read cookies script, a `window.saveAsFile` script, and MudBlazor. There are no additional scripts after `blazor.server.js`. We do not have a `pace.js` file. I tried your new items but no luck.

Comment: @NeilWehneman Are you using a self-signed certificate on the server ? Also, what shows in the Firefox WS developer tools?

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/10/firefoxs-new-websocket-inspector/

Comment: I'm seeing same issue here but only when the logout button is clicked and the Logout.cshtml is executed.